# How to calculate # of unique names in each group

Tags: r, sorting, unique, repeat

can anyone show me how to get the following done in R? I want to calculate the number of unique people in each group, like the sample showed below, the first column correspond to each group (there're 3 groups here), and second column means people's name (eg, in group 1, people A's name show up 3 times. The third column is the one I want to generate in R (if someone's name shows up x times in a certain group, then the last column should indicates x). Thank you all!

```
    x <- read.table(header=T, text="group peoplename noofuniquepeople
1 A 3
1 B 1
1 A 3
1 A 3
1 D 1
2 M 1
2 K 2
2 T 3
2 T 3
2 K 2
2 T 3
3 E 2
3 F 1
3 E 2
3 G 2
3 G 2
3 V 1")
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223308/fastest-way-to-count-occurrences-of-each-unique-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ave` and `within`:

```
within(x, Freq <- ave(1:nrow(x), peoplename, group, FUN=length))
```

Comment: this one is easy to remember, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should ideally put in what you've tried first. We can help you debug.

Anyhow,

```
> df = data.frame(N = c("A","B","A","A","D","M","K","T","T","K","T","E","F","E","G","G","V"), G = c(3,1,3,3,1,1,2,3,3,2,3,2,1,2,2,2,1))
> df
   N G
1  A 3
2  B 1
3  A 3
4  A 3
5  D 1
6  M 1
7  K 2
8  T 3
9  T 3
10 K 2
11 T 3
12 E 2
13 F 1
14 E 2
15 G 2
16 G 2
17 V 1

> numberOfGroups = length(unique(df$G))
> numberOfGroups
[1] 3

> require(plyr)
> uniqueInGroup <- dlply(df,.fun=unique,.variables=.(G))
> uniqueInGroup
$`1`
  N G
1 B 1
2 D 1
3 M 1
4 F 1
5 V 1

$`2`
  N G
1 K 2
3 E 2
5 G 2

$`3`
  N G
1 A 3
4 T 3

attr(,"split_type")
[1] "data.frame"
attr(,"split_labels")
  G
1 1
2 2
3 3

lapply(uniqueInGroup, function(x) return(length(unique(x$N))))
```

Oops, took the third col to be group. Run this script with the 1st col instead, and you'll have the required output.

Answer (score 1):

There may be better ways, but

```
x$gp     <- paste(x$group, x$peoplename)
x_new    <- merge (x, table(x$gp), by.x="gp", by.y="Var1")
x_new$gp <- NULL
```

produces

```
> x_new
   group peoplename noofuniquepeople Freq
1      1          A                3    3
2      1          A                3    3
3      1          A                3    3
4      1          B                1    1
5      1          D                1    1
6      2          K                2    2
7      2          K                2    2
8      2          M                1    1
9      2          T                3    3
10     2          T                3    3
11     2          T                3    3
12     3          E                2    2
13     3          E                2    2
14     3          F                1    1
15     3          G                2    2
16     3          G                2    2
17     3          V                1    1
```

and the last two columns are the same

Answer (score 1):

Using good old `base::aggregate` this has the advantage (in my opinion) of aggregating your data to display one row for each `group` and `peoplename` within that group. `length` gives how many times that combination occurs:

```
aggregate( . ~ peoplename + group , data = x , FUN = length )
#   peoplename group noofuniquepeople
#1           A     1                3
#2           B     1                1
#3           D     1                1
#4           K     2                2
#5           M     2                1
#6           T     2                3
#7           E     3                2
#8           F     3                1
#9           G     3                2
#10          V     3                1
```

By the way, if you input data was missing the `noofuniquepeople` column (which I assume it is because you want to calculate it) you don't need it. You can use a dummy variable to aggregate on like this:

```
Unique = rep( 1 , nrow(x) )
aggregate( Unique ~ peoplename + group , data = x , FUN = sum )
```