# R takes forever to compute a simple procedure

Tags: r, for-loop

`allWords` is a vector of 1.3 million words, with some repetition. What I want to do, is to create two vectors:

A with the word

B with the occurance of the word

So that I can later join them in a Matrix and thus associate them, like: "mom", 3 ; "pencil", 14 etc.

```
for(word in allWords){

    #get a vector with indexes for all repetitions of a word
    temp <- which(allWords==word) 
    #Make "allWords" smaller - remove duplicates
    allWords= allWords[-which(allWords==word)]
    #Calculate occurance
    occ<-length(temp)
    #store
    A = c(A,word)
    B = c(B,occ)
}
```

This for loop takes forever and I don't really know why or what I am doing wrong. Reading the 1.3 million words from a file goes as fast as 5 seconds, but performing these basic operations never lets the algorithm terminate.

Comment: You are in Circle 2 of [the R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)

Comment: Someone should give this a better title...maybe "shortening and growing objects in a loop"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the size of your vector, I think `data.table` can be a good friend in this situation_

```
> library(data.table)
> x <- c("dog", "cat", "dog")  # Ferdinand.kraft's example vector
> dtx <- data.table(x)         # converting `x` vector into a data.table object
> dtx[, .N, by="x"]            # Computing the freq for each word
     x N
1: dog 2
2: cat 1
```

Comment: The OP wants the positions, too, so... `dtx[, list(.N,occ=list(.I)), by="x"]`, I guess.

Comment: This is indeed the fastest. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17223308/fastest-way-to-count-occurrences-of-each-unique-element

Answer (score 3):

Use `table()`:

```
> table(c("dog", "cat", "dog"))

cat dog 
  1   2
```

The vectors are columns of the corresponding dataframe:

```
A <- as.data.frame(table(c("dog", "cat", "dog")))[,1]
B <- as.data.frame(table(c("dog", "cat", "dog")))[,2]
```

Result:

```
> A
[1] cat dog
Levels: cat dog
> B
[1] 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `list` to make something like hash "key:value" pairs.

```
data = c("joe", "tom", "sue", "joe", "jen")

aList = list()

for(i in data){
    if (length(aList[[i]]) == 0){
      aList[[i]] = 1
    } else {
      aList[[i]] = aList[[i]] + 1
    }
}
```

Result

```
$joe
[1] 2

$tom
[1] 1

$sue
[1] 1

$jen
[1] 1
```

Comment: The problem is the loop. This is doomed to take forever. :-)

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft, it seems you are right.  I didn't realize R would struggle with a moderate sized array. Upvote.